# Выполнить 3d-трансформацию картинки

Tags: c#, .net, изображения, graphics, обработка-изображений

Есть [картинка с экрана](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThRWY.png) и [картинка с камеры](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ygb1O.png). Во второй некая область сделана прозрачной. Под эту прозрачную область требуется поместить картинку с экрана. Сложность в том, что подкладываемую картинку надо предварительно повернуть.

На css соответствующий поворот легко делается [3d-трансформацией](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/matrix3d):

```
transform: matrix3d(.615,0,0,.00015,0,.615,0,-.000005,0,0,1,0,-151,-120,0,1);
```

Мне нужно сделать такую же трансформацию, но на VB.NET или C#. Я нашёл, как сделать [2d-трансформацию](//msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.transform(v=vs.110).aspx), но вот про 3d что-то ничего не нахожу.

**Как осуществить такую 3d-трансформацию в .NET?**

Ниже помещён сниппет для наглядной (стоит развернуть его на всю страницу) демонстрации желаемого результата. В нём при наведении мышки на проекцию экрана, она перемещается на передний план, а её граница подсвечивается. [Скрипт для масштабирования](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/594479/178988) используется исключительно для наглядности и не влияет на результат.

```js
~function(){var $window=$(window),$body=$("body");var ie= document.documentMode;function updateSizes(){var width=$window.width(),height=$window.height(),scale=Math.min(width/1920,height/1080,1);var style=$body[0].style;style.msZoom=ie===8||ie===9?scale:1;style.zoom=ie===10||ie===11?1:scale;style.mozTransform="scale("+scale+")";style.oTransform="scale("+scale+")";style.transform="scale("+scale+")";}$window.resize(updateSizes);updateSizes();}();
```

```css
html{width:100%;overflow:hidden;}body{margin:0;position:relative;transform-origin:top left;}@supports(transform:scale(1)){body{-ms-zoom:1!important;zoom:1!important;}}
.camera{pointer-events:none;}.screen:hover{z-index:2;outline:10px solid rgba(255,0,0,.5);}

body {
  width: 1920px;
  height: 1080px;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
}

.camera {
  width: 1920px;
  height: 1080px;
}

.screen {
  width: 1600px;
  height: 900px;
  transform: matrix3d(.615,0,0,.00015,0,.615,0,-.000005,0,0,1,0,-151,-120,0,1);
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img class="screen" src="//i.stack.imgur.com/ThRWY.png">
<img class="camera" src="//i.stack.imgur.com/Ygb1O.png">
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/661076/4794368

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36145/Free-Image-Transformation

Comment: А как-то попроще? Желательно не вылазия за пределы winforms.

Comment: WPF не пойдет? Там можно описать сцену прямо в XAML, будет выглядеть примерно как ваш HTML/CSS. Ну и не понятно что вам в итоге надо, сохранить итоговое изображение? Или это будет приложение-презентация?

Comment: Уточните платформу. Это будет WinForms,WPF или что-то третье (веб-сайт, вин-сервис)?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, мне надо не отобразить, а сохранить в файл. В WPF я не разбираюсь, но если оно поможет, то можно попробовать.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, предпочтительно winforms, но можно и что-то ещё. Это будет прога, которая мне просто пакетно пачку кадров обработает.

Comment: Тема достаточно объемная получилась. Надеюсь скоро докопаться до истины и дать ответ в виде *порта* функции `transform: matrix3d(...)` на `C#`)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, в смысле ты её хочешь реализовать сам? Или всё-таки стандартно как-то?

Comment: Я не нашел стандартных инструментов (без использования сторонних библиотек), так что ворошу свой метод)

Comment: Ответ @MSDN.WhiteKnight помог Вам? Или мне продолжать разбираться с матричными трансформациями в обеденных перерывах?)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov, я ещё не пытался его применить. Пока по обсуждению в чате кажется, что там придётся какие-то параметры подбирать. Так что пока сложно сказать.

Answer (score 2):

**Способ 1 - С использованием WPF**

Можно создать такой класс на основе Viewport3D из WPF:

```
//References: PresentationCore, PresentationFramework, WindowsBase, System.XAML
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace WindowsFormsTest
{
    public class ImageTransformer
    {
        /*Применяет произвольное 3D-преобразование к изображению*/
        public static void ApplyTransform(string input, string output, Matrix3D matr)
        {
            Viewport3D myViewport3D;
            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(input));

            // Declare scene objects.
            myViewport3D = new Viewport3D();
            Model3DGroup myModel3DGroup = new Model3DGroup();
            GeometryModel3D myGeometryModel = new GeometryModel3D();
            ModelVisual3D myModelVisual3D = new ModelVisual3D();
            // Defines the camera used to view the 3D object. In order to view the 3D object,
            // the camera must be positioned and pointed such that the object is within view 
            // of the camera.
            PerspectiveCamera myPCamera = new PerspectiveCamera();

            // Specify where in the 3D scene the camera is.
            myPCamera.Position = new Point3D(0, 0, Math.Max(image.PixelWidth,image.PixelHeight)*2);

            // Specify the direction that the camera is pointing.
            myPCamera.LookDirection = new Vector3D(0, 0, -1);

            // Define camera's horizontal field of view in degrees.
            myPCamera.FieldOfView = 60;

            // Asign the camera to the viewport
            myViewport3D.Camera = myPCamera;

            // Define the lights cast in the scene. Without light, the 3D object cannot 
            // be seen. Note: to illuminate an object from additional directions, create 
            // additional lights.                        
            AmbientLight al = new AmbientLight(Colors.White);
            myModel3DGroup.Children.Add(al);

            // The geometry specifes the shape of the 3D plane. In this sample, a flat sheet 
            // is created.
            MeshGeometry3D myMeshGeometry3D = new MeshGeometry3D();

            // Create a collection of normal vectors for the MeshGeometry3D.
            Vector3DCollection myNormalCollection = new Vector3DCollection();
            myNormalCollection.Add(new Vector3D(0, 0, 1));
            myNormalCollection.Add(new Vector3D(0, 0, 1));
            myNormalCollection.Add(new Vector3D(0, 0, 1));
            myNormalCollection.Add(new Vector3D(0, 0, 1));
            myNormalCollection.Add(new Vector3D(0, 0, 1));
            myNormalCollection.Add(new Vector3D(0, 0, 1));
            myMeshGeometry3D.Normals = myNormalCollection;

            // Create a collection of vertex positions for the MeshGeometry3D. 
            Point3DCollection myPositionCollection = new Point3DCollection();
            myPositionCollection.Add(new Point3D(-image.PixelWidth / 2.0, -image.PixelHeight / 2.0, 0.5));
            myPositionCollection.Add(new Point3D(image.PixelWidth / 2.0, -image.PixelHeight / 2.0, 0.5));
            myPositionCollection.Add(new Point3D(image.PixelWidth / 2.0, image.PixelHeight / 2.0, 0.5));
            myPositionCollection.Add(new Point3D(image.PixelWidth / 2.0, image.PixelHeight / 2.0, 0.5));
            myPositionCollection.Add(new Point3D(-image.PixelWidth / 2.0, image.PixelHeight / 2.0, 0.5));
            myPositionCollection.Add(new Point3D(-image.PixelWidth / 2.0, -image.PixelHeight / 2.0, 0.5));
            myMeshGeometry3D.Positions = myPositionCollection;

            // Create a collection of texture coordinates for the MeshGeometry3D.
            PointCollection myTextureCoordinatesCollection = new PointCollection();

            Point p5 = new Point(0, 0);
            Point p34 = new Point(1, 0);
            Point p2 = new Point(1, 1);
            Point p16 = new Point(0, 1);

            myTextureCoordinatesCollection.Add(p16);
            myTextureCoordinatesCollection.Add(p2);
            myTextureCoordinatesCollection.Add(p34);
            myTextureCoordinatesCollection.Add(p34);
            myTextureCoordinatesCollection.Add(p5);
            myTextureCoordinatesCollection.Add(p16);

            myMeshGeometry3D.TextureCoordinates = myTextureCoordinatesCollection;

            // Create a collection of triangle indices for the MeshGeometry3D.
            Int32Collection myTriangleIndicesCollection = new Int32Collection();
            myTriangleIndicesCollection.Add(0);
            myTriangleIndicesCollection.Add(1);
            myTriangleIndicesCollection.Add(2);
            myTriangleIndicesCollection.Add(3);
            myTriangleIndicesCollection.Add(4);
            myTriangleIndicesCollection.Add(5);
            myMeshGeometry3D.TriangleIndices = myTriangleIndicesCollection;

            // Apply the mesh to the geometry model.
            myGeometryModel.Geometry = myMeshGeometry3D;

            // The material specifies the material applied to the 3D object.

            ImageBrush br = new ImageBrush(image);

            // Define material and apply to the mesh geometries.
            DiffuseMaterial myMaterial = new DiffuseMaterial(br);
            myGeometryModel.Material = myMaterial;
            myGeometryModel.BackMaterial = myMaterial;

            MatrixTransform3D transform = new MatrixTransform3D(matr);
            myGeometryModel.Transform = transform;

            // Add the geometry model to the model group.
            myModel3DGroup.Children.Add(myGeometryModel);

            // Add the group of models to the ModelVisual3d.
            myModelVisual3D.Content = myModel3DGroup;
            myViewport3D.Children.Add(myModelVisual3D);

            //render Viewport3D into bitmap      
            int width = image.PixelWidth ;
            int height = image.PixelHeight;
            myViewport3D.Width = width;
            myViewport3D.Height = height;
            myViewport3D.Measure(new Size(width, height));
            myViewport3D.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, width, height));

            RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
            rtb.Render(myViewport3D);

            //Save bitmap to file
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(output, FileMode.Create))
            {
                BitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
                encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));
                encoder.Save(fileStream);
            }

        }

        /*Поворачивает изображение вокруг указанной оси на указанный угол*/
        public static void RotateImage(string input, string output, Vector3D axis, int angle)
        {
            var myRotateTransform3D = new RotateTransform3D();
            var myAxisAngleRotation3d = new AxisAngleRotation3D();
            myAxisAngleRotation3d.Axis = axis;
            myAxisAngleRotation3d.Angle = angle;
            myRotateTransform3D.Rotation = myAxisAngleRotation3d;

            ImageTransformer.ApplyTransform(input, output, myRotateTransform3D.Value);

        }

    }
}
```

Пример использования (поворот на 30 градусов вокруг оси Y):

```
ImageTransformer.RotateImage( 
    "c:\\images\\image.jpg", 
    "c:\\images\\image2.jpg",
    new System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Vector3D(0, 1, 0), 
    30);
```

Применение произвольного преобразования, заданного матрицей:

```
ImageTransformer.ApplyTransform(
   "c:\\images\\image.jpg",
   "c:\\images\\image2.jpg",
   new System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Matrix3D(.615, 0, 0, .00015, 0, .615, 0, -.000005, 0, 0, 1, 0, -151, -120, 0, 1));
```

При использовании в проекте WinForms нужно добавить ссылки на необходимые сборки, но делать отдельный поток для обработки сообщений WPF (Application.Run) не обязательно.

**Способ 2 - С использованием MSHTML**

При наличии IE 10+ можно программно растеризовать приведенный HTML+CSS с помощью такого кода:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.ComponentModel;
//Reference: COM -> Microsoft HTML Object Library

namespace WindowsFormsTest
{
    public class HtmlVisualizer
    {
        public static void DrawHtml(string content, string output)
        {
            RECTL rcClient = new RECTL();
            bool b = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETWORKAREA, 0, ref rcClient, 0);
            if (b == false) { rcClient.bottom = 480; rcClient.right = 640; }

            int width = (int)(rcClient.right - rcClient.left);
            int height = (int)(rcClient.bottom - rcClient.top);
            IntPtr screendc = GetDC(IntPtr.Zero);


            mshtml.HTMLDocument doc = null;
            mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 d2 = null;
            IOleObject pObj = null;
            IViewObject pView = null;

            try
            {
                doc = new mshtml.HTMLDocument(); //создание документа
                d2 = (mshtml.IHTMLDocument2)doc;
                int hr;

                //установка размера документа
                pObj = (IOleObject)d2;
                SIZEL sz = new SIZEL();

                sz.x = (uint)MulDiv(width, HIMETRIC_INCH, GetDeviceCaps(screendc, LOGPIXELSX));
                sz.y = (uint)MulDiv(height, HIMETRIC_INCH, GetDeviceCaps(screendc, LOGPIXELSY));
                ;
                hr = pObj.SetExtent((int)System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.DVASPECT.DVASPECT_CONTENT, ref sz);
                if (hr != 0) throw Marshal.GetExceptionForHR(hr);

                d2.write(content);
                d2.close();                

                while (d2.readyState != "complete") System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents(); 

                //преобразование в Bitmap
                pView = (IViewObject)d2;
                Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height);
                Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
                using (g)
                {

                    IntPtr hdc = g.GetHdc();
                    hr = pView.Draw((int)System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.DVASPECT.DVASPECT_CONTENT,
                        -1, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, hdc, ref rcClient, IntPtr.Zero,
                        IntPtr.Zero, 0);
                    if (hr != 0) throw Marshal.GetExceptionForHR(hr);
                    g.ReleaseHdc(hdc);
                }

                //сохранение в PNG
                bmp.Save(output, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);


            }
            finally
            {
                //освобождение ресурсов                
                if (d2 != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(d2);
                if (pObj != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pObj);
                if (pView != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pView);
                if (doc != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(doc);
            }
        }

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        static extern int GetDeviceCaps(IntPtr hdc, int nIndex);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetDC(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(int nAction, int nParam, ref RECTL rc, int nUpdate);

        public static int MulDiv(int number, int numerator, int denominator)
        {
            return (int)(((long)number * numerator) / denominator);
        }

        const int LOGPIXELSX = 88;
        const int LOGPIXELSY = 90;
        const int HIMETRIC_INCH = 2540;
        const int SPI_GETWORKAREA = 48;

    }

    [ComImport()]
    [GuidAttribute("0000010d-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
    [InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface IViewObject
    {
        int Draw([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int dwDrawAspect, int lindex, IntPtr pvAspect, IntPtr ptd, IntPtr hdcTargetDev, IntPtr hdcDraw,
            ref RECTL lprcBounds, IntPtr lprcWBounds, IntPtr pfnContinue, int dwContinue);
        int a();
        int b();
        int c();
        int d();
        int e();
    }

    [ComImport()]
    [Guid("00000112-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface IOleObject
    {
        void f();
        void g();
        void SetHostNames(object szContainerApp, object szContainerObj);
        void Close(uint dwSaveOption);
        void SetMoniker(uint dwWhichMoniker, object pmk);
        void GetMoniker(uint dwAssign, uint dwWhichMoniker, object ppmk);
        void x();
        void y();
        void DoVerb(uint iVerb, uint lpmsg, object pActiveSite, uint lindex, uint hwndParent, uint lprcPosRect);
        void EnumVerbs(ref object ppEnumOleVerb);
        void Update();
        void IsUpToDate();
        void GetUserClassID(uint pClsid);
        void GetUserType(uint dwFormOfType, uint pszUserType);
        int SetExtent(uint dwDrawAspect, ref SIZEL psizel);
        void GetExtent(uint dwDrawAspect, uint psizel);
        void Advise(object pAdvSink, uint pdwConnection);
        void Unadvise(uint dwConnection);
        void EnumAdvise(ref object ppenumAdvise);
        void GetMiscStatus(uint dwAspect, uint pdwStatus);
        void SetColorScheme(object pLogpal);
    };

    public struct RECTL
    {
        public uint left;
        public uint top;
        public uint right;
        public uint bottom;
    }

    public struct SIZEL
    {
        public uint x;
        public uint y;
    }
}
```

На вход подавать HTML такого вида:

```html
<html><head>

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />    
<style>
html{width:100%;overflow:hidden;}body{margin:0;position:relative;transform-origin:top left;}@supports(transform:scale(1)){body{-ms-zoom:1!important;zoom:1!important;}}
.camera{pointer-events:none;}.screen:hover{z-index:2;outline:10px solid rgba(255,0,0,.5);}

body {
  width: 1920px;
  height: 1080px;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
}

.camera {
  width: 1920px;
  height: 1080px;
}

.screen {
  width: 1600px;
  height: 900px;
  transform: matrix3d(.615,0,0,.00015,0,.615,0,-.000005,0,0,1,0,-151,-120,0,1);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<img class="screen" src="file://localhost/c:/images/screen.png">
<img class="camera" src="file://localhost/c:/images/kamera.png">
</body></html>
```

**Источники:**

[How to: Create a 3-D Scene](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-create-a-3-d-scene)

[Projecting an object into a scene based on world coordinates only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945762/projecting-an-object-into-a-scene-based-on-world-coordinates-only)

[wpf, c#, renderTargetBitmap of viewport3D without assigning it to a window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10208798/wpf-c-rendertargetbitmap-of-viewport3d-without-assigning-it-to-a-window/10231068)

[Using IE to Save SVGs as Bitmaps to Wherever](http://paige-rudnick.com/2014/01/30/using-ie-to-save-svgs-as-bitmaps-to-wherever/)

Comment: А как числа из вопроса перевесит в то, что в ответе?

Comment: @Qwertiy Если нужна именно матрица преобразования, думаю, лучше будет вместо RotateTransform3D использовать [MatrixTransform3D](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.media.media3d.matrixtransform3d(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Ну матрицы мне вроде хватает, а как твой код использовать я не пойму - слишком много каких-то чисел...

Comment: @Qwertiy добавил метод для произвольного преобразования на основе матрицы. Но такую же матрицу, как в примере на CSS, использовать не получиться, так как в ней слишком большой компонент смещения (изображение улетает за пределы видимости камеры). Смещение нужно убрать и потом применить уже при 2d-обработке.

Comment: А почему улетает? И почему на css не улетает?